# pgfplots: How to plot Cassini curves by using (only) pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I want to plot [Cassini curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cassini_oval) with `pgfplot` (avoiding `gnuplot`)

For `a=1` and `c=1.7` the function `r(\p)=sqrt(a^2*cos(2*\p)+sqrt(a^4*(cos(2*\p))^2+(c^4-a^4)))` should give something like a (cassinian) oval.

But I get a strange spiral:

[image]

What do I have to do?

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
declare function={
a=1;
c=1.7;
r(\p)=sqrt(a^2*cos(2*\p)+sqrt(a^4*(cos(2*\p))^2+(c^4-a^4)));
},
]
\begin{axis}[
axis lines=center,
axis equal,
enlargelimits=true,
%smooth, 
samples=222,
]
\addplot[data cs=polar, red, domain=0:360] (x,{r(x)});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`r(x)` is reserved. Remember always to set the compat level -see code.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
declare function={
a=1;
c=1.7;
cassini(\p)=sqrt(a^2*cos(2*\p)+sqrt(a^4*(cos(2*\p))^2+(c^4-a^4)));
},
]
\begin{axis}[
axis lines=center,
axis equal,
enlargelimits=true,
]
\addplot[data cs=polar, red, domain=0:360, samples=100, smooth] (x,{cassini(x)});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Oval in a graph]

For `c=0.7`

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
declare function={
a=1;
c=0.7;
cassinip(\p)=sqrt(a^2*cos(2*\p)+sqrt(a^4*(cos(2*\p))^2+(c^4-a^4)));
cassinin(\p)=sqrt(a^2*cos(2*\p)-sqrt(a^4*(cos(2*\p))^2+(c^4-a^4)));
},
]
\begin{axis}[
axis lines=center,
axis equal,
enlargelimits=true,
unbounded coords=jump,
]
\addplot[data cs=polar, red, domain=0:360, samples=1000, smooth] (x,{cassinip(x)});
\addplot[data cs=polar, red, domain=0:360, samples=1000, smooth] (x,{cassinin(x)});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Two broken circles in a graph]

Here I have increased `samples` to an absurd amount to get closer to the true curve - closed circles.
Consider not using polar coordinates, as the singularities are much more easily dealt with in x-y coordinates. E.g. with `y filter/.expression` like here https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/587018/8650

Comment: Ah nice. Seems to work in nearly all  cases `a=1` and `c=1` (Lemniscate) or `c=1.2` (oval with saddle) or `c=1.7` (oval without saddle). Only `c=0.7` (two single ovals) will not work; maybe there is something wrong with the math.

Comment: You are plotting a polar `function` - that means only one value for each angle. -be careful with the math when taking `sqrt` on both sides. To see a more correct plot, where wrong ends are not connected, use `unbounded coords=jump`

Comment: Yes, I tried `unbounded coords=jump` but the case `c=0.7` seems to be not correct. If you want or if you have an idea, you could add that special case.

Comment: TYVM .............................